# MediaRecorder orientation hint

Tags: android, orientation, android-mediarecorder, android-camera2

I'm trying to record videos using camera2 api 
But when I try to set orientation or media recorder, the video is recorded upside down
It's working fine in Nexus5X but in other phones it's showing upside down

How to set the orientation correctly for mediarecorder so it works for all devices

Thanks

Comment: you want to fix dimension or orientation? try to use that for the orientation may this resolve your issue mediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);
        if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
            if (!cameraFront)
                mediaRecorder.setOrientationHint(90);
            else
                mediaRecorder.setOrientationHint(270);

        }

Comment: I want to fix orientation
I'm using mMediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.SURFACE);

Comment: if you are using camera2 api you can directly put camera instead of Surface

Comment: try to use the one comment i send

Comment: if you still not able to resolve i will share my whole source code for using the camera at fix orientation.

Comment: It's now resolved 
I referred google2 video recording code available in github
https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Video/blob/master/Application/src/main/java/com/example/android/camera2video/Camera2VideoFragment.java

Thanks

Comment: wait i will update my answer. it not resolve but we can use that as per our requirement of the optimal use. It working fine in my project hope that helpful for you also

Answer (score 0):

As per the above question requirement we want to fix the camera orientation while recording the video. This is one of the challenging issue i face the same problem with my code.

> camera.setDisplayOrientation(90);

Will make the Camera to rotate to 90 degree and This may result in not suitable Orientation for some devices.

So I try to do that with this way hope the below code will help you.

The first thing we want to do to start preview of the camera:

```
  private void startCameraPreview() {
    releaseCamera();
    if (!previewing) {
        previewing = true;

        try {
            camera = Camera.open(cameraId);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            camera = null;
        }
        if (null == camera) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Camera unavailable! Please retry after restarting the phone.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT)
            setOptimalPreviewSize();
        else
            setLandScapOptimalPreviewSize();


        if (camera != null) {
            if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT)
                camera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
            try {
                camera.setPreviewDisplay(previewSv.getHolder());
                camera.startPreview();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    callback = new SurfaceHolder.Callback() {

        @Override
        public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            stopCameraPreview();
        }

        @Override
        public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {

        }

        @Override
        public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
            holder.removeCallback(callback);
            if (previewing) {
                stopCameraPreview();
            }
            startCameraPreview();
        }
    };
    previewSv.getHolder().addCallback(callback);
}
```

here at below code i want to use optimal preview size for that i am using this function:

```
   private void setOptimalPreviewSize() {
    if (null != camera && null != previewSv) {
        Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
        List<Camera.Size> sizes = null != parameters ? parameters.getSupportedPreviewSizes() : null;
        if (null != sizes && previewSv.getWidth() > 0 && previewSv.getHeight() > 0) {
            Camera.Size optimalSize = CameraHelper.getOptimalPreviewSize(sizes, dispSize.y, dispSize.x);
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = previewSv.getLayoutParams();
            float aspectRatio = (float) optimalSize.width / (float) optimalSize.height;
            params.width = dispSize.x;
            params.height = (int) ((float) params.width * aspectRatio);
            previewSv.setLayoutParams(params);
            parameters.setPreviewSize(optimalSize.width, optimalSize.height);
            camera.setParameters(parameters);
            System.out.println("setOptimalPreviewSize() optimalSize=" + optimalSize);
        }
    } else {
        System.err.println("setOptimalPreviewSize() failed - camera null");
    }
}
```

and for the LandScape mode i use that for the prefer size

```
   private void setLandScapOptimalPreviewSize() {
    if (null != camera && null != previewSv) {
        Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
        List<Camera.Size> sizes = null != parameters ? parameters.getSupportedPreviewSizes() : null;
        if (null != sizes && previewSv.getWidth() > 0 && previewSv.getHeight() > 0) {
            Camera.Size optimalSize = CameraHelper.getOptimalPreviewSize(sizes, dispSize.y, dispSize.x);
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = previewSv.getLayoutParams();
            float aspectRatio = (float) optimalSize.width / (float) optimalSize.height;
            params.height = dispSize.x;
            params.width = (int) ((float) params.height * aspectRatio);
            previewSv.setLayoutParams(params);
            parameters.setPreviewSize(optimalSize.width, optimalSize.height);
            camera.setParameters(parameters);
            System.out.println("setOptimalPreviewSize() optimalSize=" + optimalSize);
        }
    } else {
        System.err.println("setOptimalPreviewSize() failed - camera null");
    }
}
```

Now as per my project requirement i have to open the video preview at half of the screen and image at half of the screen so i am going to share my whole activity with you where you can delete the code for the image if you don't required that.

create one Actvity ImageVideoActivity.java https://gist.github.com/anonymous/8c776a350098cb3346239dd72b5564b3

now the xml https://gist.github.com/anonymous/bb9fe7c2b3a86e411f0323a06623ead8

here is your BaseActvity.java

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/451336f3b0f420f8d01e6b4d6659762f

here is your camera helper class
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/1018b5145d013aa5300b577010b1ca6b

here is your TextureVideoView.java
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/a7f7ba92d1548b867e4fd487083ab67a

My constants file
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/9419c64fbb0410a9a16248956ea096ac

Hope this answer resolve your problem.If you face any issue with code get back with comment.we try to resolve that together. 
Good Day!!!